# Sistema de Menu y cabecera fija que arroja error

Tags: php, html5

Me metí en un problemón que por ahí pueden orientarme (ya que estoy haciendo mis primeras armas con el tema de desarrollos web):
Tengo un sitio que tiene una estructura mas o menos asi:

- carpeta "css": archivos dentro
- carpeta "js": archivos dentro
- carpeta "paginas": subcarpetas dentro: archivos dentro

a continuación en la raíz del sitio tengo archivos como: 
index.php
cabecera.php
menu.php
pagina1.php
pagina2.php
pagina3.php
etc...

ahora bien... vi que haciendo lo siguiente, lograba evitar repetir código:

```
 <header>
    <?php
        include 'cabecera.php';
    ?>
</header>
```

y en el body pongo lo siguiente:

```
<?php 
    include 'menu.php';
 ?>
```

ahora bien, cuando quiero aplicar la misma rutina con las paginas que estan en diversas otras carpetas del sitio, me arroja un error 404 !!!
Creo que tengo un problema con los links que hay dentro de cada uno de esos archivos cabecera.php y menu.php
Alguna sugerencia al respecto ? 
Desde ya muchas gracias

esta es la cabecera:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5" id="bloque">
    <div class="container-fluid logo_mayor">
       <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Placeholder image" width="400" class="img-responsive center-block" class="cabecera"> 
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4" id="bloque">
     <span class="align-middle" style="color: red">
      <h4 class="align-bottom" style="padding-bottom: 20px"><i><strong>Slogan de la página</strong></i></h4>
    </span>
   </div>

  <div class="col-sm-3" id="bloque">
   <?php
     include 'social.php';
   ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

este es el codigo del menu:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!--Si es administrador la barra de menu es negra -->     
    <nav class='navbar navbar-default'>
      <div class='container-fluid'>
        <div class='navbar-header'>
            <button type='button' class='navbar-toggle collapsed' data-toggle='collapse' data-target='#navbar' aria-expanded='false' aria-controls='navbar'>
                <span class='sr-only'>Men&uacute;</span>
                <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                <span class='icon-bar'></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="images/findergreen-iso.png" width="20"></a>
        </div>

            <div id='navbar' class='navbar-collapse collapse'>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Menu<span class="caret"></span></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="button"><a href="../abms/A/opcion1.php">opcion1</a></li>
                        <li class="button"><a href="#">opcion 1.5</a></li>
                        <li class="button"><a href="../abms/B/opcion2.php">opcion 2</a></li>
                        <li class="button"><a href="../abms/C/opcion3.php">opcion 3</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="login.php">Ingresar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="registro.php">Registrarse</a></li>
                    <li class="button"><a href="../abms/d/d.php">opcion D</a></li>
                    <li class="button"><a href="../abms/e/e.php">opcion E</a></li>
                    <li class="button"><a href="../forms/noticias/noticias.php">Novedades</a></li>

                </ul>
                <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
                    <li><a href='fundamentos.php'>Fundamentos</a></li>
                </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    </nav>  
   </div>
```

Comment: Creo que te falto agregar mucho código, ¿Podrías volver a revisar la pregunta por favor?

Comment: ¿Los include que te dan error los estas poniendo solo con el nombre de la pagina o con la ruta relativa?

Comment: ahora pongo los codigos de la cabecera, los del menu es parecido... maneja links relativos... porque probe poner links absolutos y me arroja error tambien

Comment: hola amigo creo que te falta aun bastente codigo

Comment: Solo te va a encontrar social.php si esta al mismo nivel que las otras, si no lo esta tendras que usar rutas relativas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu lo has dicho "diversas otras carpetas". El error 404 es porque estas incluyendo un archivo que no existe y es precisamente `menu.php` o todos los demas archivos que no esten al mismo nivel que el archivo en cuestion.

Me imagino con *"diversas otras carpetas"* seria asi :

```
css
js
paginas
    menu.php
    cabecera.php
    diversa_carpeta_1
       archivo_diverso.php <---- include '/menu.php';
    diversa_carpeta_2
       archivo_diverso2.php <---- include '/menu.php';
```

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhh buen dato !!! Pero tengo un problema... el menú lo carga, pero los links no funcionan, y las imagenes (logo y otras) no las carga... creo que deberé usar direcciones absolutas

Comment: puedes publicar el codigo que hay en tu menu.php

Comment: funciona bien en las paginas que estan en la raiz... pero cuando me muevo a paginas donde estan mas adentro en la raiz... se rompe todo